# Populating data frame through loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to populate data frame through loop. I succeeded for a certain extent but not able to bind that loop within a function

```
iterations = 34
variables = 6
v_log <- matrix(ncol=variables, nrow=iterations)

for (i in 1:34)
{
    v_log[i,]<-c(1,"c1", "c2","c3", "c4", "c5")
}
v_log1=as.data.frame(v_log)
```

but when I am trying to bind them within the function,

```
f1<- function() {

iterations = 34
variables = 6
v_log <- matrix(ncol=variables, nrow=iterations)

for (i in 1:34)
{
    v_log[i,]<-c(1,"c1", "c2","c3", "c4", "c5")
}
v_log1=as.data.frame(v_log)
}
```

On the execution of function, like f1() nothing will populate.

Please help.

Comment: You need to assign the output of f1 to a named object or it will just be garbage collected. Welcome to functional programming. You have left the SAS/SPSS macro-processor domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should produce a result. You need to assign the output of f1 to a named object or it will just be garbage collected. Welcome to functional programming. You have left the SAS/SPSS macro-processor domain:

```
> test <- f1()
> str(test)
'data.frame':   34 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "c1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V3: Factor w/ 1 level "c2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V4: Factor w/ 1 level "c3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "c4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V6: Factor w/ 1 level "c5": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```